# Problems with html?

Tags: html, css

I have some work for school to do and I'm having some problems.
[image: random screenshot]
I need the menu to be in the center but it doesn't work.

[image: Expected result]
My teacher didnt help me at all so I thought this web could.

This is my code so far:

```css
* {
  background-color: #62544f;
  color: black;
}
#kk {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  grid-column: 1 /span 3;
  border: #ffffff;
  border-style: solid;
  
}

article {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #62544f;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto min-content;
}

article div {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  height: 3rem;
}
body {
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  
}

#kafe  {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 208px;
  left: 166px;
  top: 15px;

  background: url(hand-drawn-of-hot-coffee-with-roasted-coffee-beans-iam-nee-removebg-preview.png);
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 10px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21));
}
```

```html
<img id="kafe" src="./obrazky/kavicka.png" alt="kava" />
<img id="bob" src="./obrazky/bbb.png" alt="kávové semínka??"/>
<img id="logo" src="./obrazky/logo.png" alt="logo"/>

<div><h1 id="kk">MENU</h1> </div>

<main>
  <h1>KÁVA</h1>
  <article>
    <h2>Luongo</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>40,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Espresso</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>40,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Americano</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>55,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Cappucinno</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>55,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Café latte</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>60,-</h3>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>flat white</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>70,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Mocha</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>70,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Ledová káva</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>70,-</h3>
  </article>
</main>
<main>
  <h1>NÁPOJE</h1>
  <article>
    <h2>coca-cola</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>30,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Kofola</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>40,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Sprite</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>30,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Fanta</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>35,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Cappy</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>35,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Limonáda</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>60,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Perlivá voda</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>25,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>voda</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>15,-</h3>
  </article>
</main>
<main>
  <h1>SLADKÉ</h1>
  <article>
    <h2>Palačinky</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>55,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Medovník</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>25,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Tiramisu</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>30,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Cheesecake</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>30,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Míša řez</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>30,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>brownies</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>35,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Mrkový dort</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>35,-</h3>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Makronky</h2>
    <div></div>
    <h3>15,-</h3>
  </article>
</main>
```

I was sure this is supposed to put the menu in its place but it didnt.
Any help would be appreciated, Im really desperate.

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow. please [edit] your question and try to be clear about what you have tried (exactly) and what you need help to solve. I have removed all the unnecesary sentences, but you need to add some more information, or it will most likely be closed. try to imagine yourself coming across this question. What would you need to answer it?

Comment: Did you mean to order your `<img>` elements and the menu's `<div>` element differently?  The `<body>` styling is set to `display: grid`, so it's displaying as a grid.  This may be a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with your browser's development tools.  Take a look at the DOM explorer (at least in Chrome) and observe how it lets you highlight elements on the page and see the exact styling applied to those elements.  When you do this, is there a specific style which isn't doing what you expect?

Comment: Hi, You can try to add your code a code-snippet. Or you can try to recreate the same environment/issue on a online playground like https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codesandbox.io/ This way you have a minimal reproducible example for people to check, and to respond upon

Edit: I saw it was edited as a code snippet. Make sure to add placeholder images to recreate the issue, as the images you used are available locally thus it does not load properly on the snippet. I suggest using https://placekitten.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
body {
  min-height: 93vh;
  margin: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  background-color: #62544f;
  color: black;
}

nav.header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 150px;
}

#kk {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 5px 25px;
}

.head-img {
  width: 100px;
}


/* set the width of images from here */

.head-img img {
  width: auto;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  row-gap: 5em;
  column-gap: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
}

article {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #62544f;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto min-content;
}

article div {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  height: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="header">
    <div class="head-img">
      <img id="kafe" src="./obrazky/kavicka.png" alt="kava" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1 id="kk">MENU</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="head-img">
      <img id="bob" src="./obrazky/bbb.png" alt="kávové semínka??" />
    </div>
    <img id="logo" src="./obrazky/logo.png" alt="logo" />
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <main>
      <h1>KÁVA</h1>
      <article>
        <h2>Luongo</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>40,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Espresso</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>40,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Americano</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>55,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Cappucinno</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>55,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Café latte</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>60,-</h3>
      </article>

      <article>
        <h2>flat white</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>70,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Mocha</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>70,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Ledová káva</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>70,-</h3>
      </article>
    </main>
    <main>
      <h1>NÁPOJE</h1>
      <article>
        <h2>coca-cola</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>30,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Kofola</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>40,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Sprite</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>30,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Fanta</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>35,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Cappy</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>35,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Limonáda</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>60,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Perlivá voda</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>25,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>voda</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>15,-</h3>
      </article>
    </main>
    <main>
      <h1>SLADKÉ</h1>
      <article>
        <h2>Palačinky</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>55,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Medovník</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>25,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Tiramisu</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>30,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Cheesecake</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>30,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Míša řez</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>30,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>brownies</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>35,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Mrkový dort</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>35,-</h3>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h2>Makronky</h2>
        <div></div>
        <h3>15,-</h3>
      </article>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

Okay, so first of all I have enclosed the three images and the "menu" heading within a `nav` and turned it into a flexbox. I've also put the images into a `div` so your code is more organized and easier to understand. Also specified their widths to centre them properly within the flexbox. I applied `position: relative` to the parent `nav` elements and then applied `position: absolute` to the `#logo` image within it so it moves relative to it's parent element when positioned.

I could've had messed up the order of images as I cannot understand Czech. But hopefully you can fix that.

I cleaned up your code and organized it, also enclosed the menu into a `div.container` and turned it into a flexbox so it's responsive when you zoom in and out of the webpage. Hopefully this helps <3

HTML:

```
<body>
    <nav class="header">
      <div class="head-img">
        <img id="kafe" src="./obrazky/kavicka.png" alt="kava" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1 id="kk">MENU</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="head-img">
        <img id="bob" src="./obrazky/bbb.png" alt="kávové semínka??" />
      </div>
      <img id="logo" src="./obrazky/logo.png" alt="logo" />
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <main>
        <h1>KÁVA</h1>
        <article>
          <h2>Luongo</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>40,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Espresso</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>40,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Americano</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>55,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Cappucinno</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>55,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Café latte</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>60,-</h3>
        </article>

        <article>
          <h2>flat white</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>70,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Mocha</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>70,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Ledová káva</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>70,-</h3>
        </article>
      </main>
      <main>
        <h1>NÁPOJE</h1>
        <article>
          <h2>coca-cola</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>30,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Kofola</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>40,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Sprite</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>30,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Fanta</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>35,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Cappy</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>35,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Limonáda</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>60,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Perlivá voda</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>25,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>voda</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>15,-</h3>
        </article>
      </main>
      <main>
        <h1>SLADKÉ</h1>
        <article>
          <h2>Palačinky</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>55,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Medovník</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>25,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Tiramisu</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>30,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Cheesecake</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>30,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Míša řez</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>30,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>brownies</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>35,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Mrkový dort</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>35,-</h3>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Makronky</h2>
          <div></div>
          <h3>15,-</h3>
        </article>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  min-height: 93vh;
  margin: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  background-color: #62544f;
  color: black;
}

nav.header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 150px;
}

#kk {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 5px 25px;
}

.head-img {
  width: 150px;
}

/* set the width of images from here */

.head-img img {
  width: auto;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  row-gap: 5em;
  column-gap: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
}

article {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #62544f;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto min-content;
}

article div {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  height: 2rem;
}
```

Screenshot: [image: website]

Comment: Please edit your answer and turn your code into a runnable snippet.

Comment: I've done that now! Open it in a full page to see the correct results.

Comment: @Envy - Thank you so much You probably saved me from failing my class <3 (hope this will reach you this is confusing page)